# What is equivalent of history.go(-1); in mozilla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        var data = {rand: Math.random()};
        window.history.pushState(data, '', '');
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
            history.go(-1);
    //location.reload();
        });
      }
```

i used above code for reloading a page on browser back button but its not working in mozilla... also it disabling forward button from chrome... Is there any way to reload previous page without hardcoded url??? 
    Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: Also remove this line: `window.location.href = window.location.href;` since it might reload the page.

Comment: What about `history.back()`...?

Comment: same problem... its working in chrome but not in mozilla

Answer (score 1):

A simple call of

```
window.history.back();
```

should work in all common browsers to navigate back. See

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

For more complex navigation in the history I can recommend the History.js lib:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: i want to reload a page on browser back button click... that is why i wrote it in popstate event where i am getting back button click but in mozilla it is not reloading a page

Comment: how to activate browser forward button in above code ??? I guess history.pushstate deactivate it

Comment: You could use 
    window.history.back(); and location.reload(); 
you can use
    window.history.forward(); to go forward.